# Поломка bind'ов команд в Linux Xfce4

Tags: linux, клавиатура, ввод, xfce4

У меня возникла на ровном месте **(с конкретными действиями связать не могу)** проблема с этими bind'ами в **Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia Xfce**: *Ctrl+Alt+T* - `x-terminal-emulator`, *Super+P* -  `xfce4-display-settings --minimal`, *Ctrl+Alt+Delete* - `xflock4` (xflock4 итак не работает), *Ctrl+Alt+L* - `xflock4`. Все эти bind'ы стоят по умолчанию, но помимо них есть ещё стандартные сочетания клавиш, и они работают.

Что я пробовал:

- Перезагружал систему
- Менял раскладку
- Проверял, не заняты ли эти сочетания другими bind'ами
- Сбрасывал настройки bind'ов до настроек по умолчанию (хотя я их ни разу не менял)
- Назначал действие на другое сочетание, тогда оно работало
- Назначал действие на другое сочетание  и обратно, на стандартном bind'е оно не работает
- Сбрасывал все настройки клавиатуры до настроек по умолчанию, в результате чего узнал, что они работают на стандартных сочетаниях, если не убирать настройку *"Использовать стандартные настройки клавиатуры"*. Однако, в таком случае я не могу использовать сочетание *Alt+Shift*, так как оно не входит в стандартные настройки, соответственно приходится использовать иконку раскладки.

Извиняюсь за обилие запятых, заранее спасибо.

Comment: В настройка Комбинации клавиш - ' exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator  Ctrl+Alt+T' или  ' exo-open -- xfce4-terminal  Ctrl+Alt+T' Но у народа слетает конфигурация после апдейтов

Answer (score 0):

[PPA with patched xserver-xorg to fix bug 865(xorg-hotkeys)](https://launchpad.net/%7Enrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys)
Xorg X server with the patch for freedesktop bug 865 (need to kick hotkeys on release, not press)
Warranty disclaimer: packages were tested in

- 16.04 LTS with HWE (Unity, MATE, Xfce)
- 18.04 LTS (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Xfce)
- 18.10 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Xfce)
- 19.04 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Unity, Xfce)
- 19.10 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Unity, Xfce)
- 20.04 LTS (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Unity, Xfce)

Но я бы действовал с осторожностью. Если решите ставить - предварительно сделайте снимок системы с Timeshift. На Linux Mint 19.3 MATE я таких проблем не наблюдаю.

Есть еще вариант установки sudo apt-get install xbindkeys-config(Графика)
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys(cli)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Как освобожусь, попробую