# Переключение русской-английской раскладки в ubuntu+MATE по Ctrl+Shift

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Уважаемые господа,

у меня идиотский вопрос, но поиск и попытки разобраться самостоятельно пока не помогли.

Я включил в Ubuntu 18 c destrop environment MATE привычный мне способ переключения между русской - английской раскладками клавиатуры по Ctrl+Shift (вообще говоря, по Left Ctrl+Left Shift, но это не очень важно)

И переключение работает прекрасно. Никаких нареканий.

Но вот все комбинации клавиш, в котрых были задействованы Ctrl+Shift - работать перестали. То есть, например, вместо выделения целого слова по Ctrl+Shift + стрелка - переключается язык. При попытке скомпилировать код в VSC по Ctrl+Shift+B в VSC - переключается язык...

Нет ли какого то способа оставить привычный способ переключения, но чтобы комбинации клавиш при этом опять работали?

Спасибо заранее, а то задолбало уже... Привожу картинку настроек - на всякий случай.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это [старый баг/фича](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865) вызванная тем, что `xkb` регистрирует смену раскладки по нажатию клавиш, а не отпусканию... если уж очень хочется поправить, то можно накатить старый патчик на иксы (потребуется пересборка)... но сейчас все модные ребята переключают раскладку `CapsLock`'ом...

Comment: Забавно. Использую тоже Ctrl+Shift на MATE. Сам патч https://launchpad.net/~nrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys или sudo apt-get install xbindkeys-config или xbindkeys(cli). Недавно отвечал на подобный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1192514/Поломка-bindов-команд-в-linux-xfce4/1192753#1192753 Сам не использовал. Для меня это не критично